# Why is "this" in an anonymous function undefined when using strict?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, use-strict

Why is **this** in an anonymous function undefined when using javascript in strict mode? I understand why this could make sense, but I couldn't find any concrete answer.

Example:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    this.foo = "bar"; // *this* is undefined, why?
}());
```

Test in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pyr5g/1/
Check out the logger (firebug).

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with anonymous functions, but the invocation method. See [this modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pyr5g/3/) (look in the console log).

Comment: @Phrogz: This may be where some of the confusion came from. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

It's because, until ECMAscript 262 edition 5, there was a big confusion if people who where using the `constructor pattern`, forgot to use the `new` keyword. If you forgot to use `new` when calling a constructor function in ES3, `this` referenced the global object (`window` in a browser) and you would clobber the global object with variables.

That was terrible behavior and so people at ECMA decided, just to set `this` to `undefined`.

Example:

```
function myConstructor() {
    this.a = 'foo';
    this.b = 'bar';
}

myInstance     = new myConstructor(); // all cool, all fine. a and b were created in a new local object
myBadInstance  = myConstructor(); // oh my gosh, we just created a, and b on the window object
```

The last line would throw an error in ES5 strict

```
"TypeError: this is undefined"
```

(which is a much better behavior)

Comment: This makes sense. Do you have a reference to back up the statement?

Comment: @RobW: I would have to search myself, But I heard Douglas Crockford several times where he said, this was the reason for that decision.

Comment: It is mentioned in JavaScript: The Good Parts by Crockford. It is described in detail. Not about ECMAs decision, though.

Comment: @madr: I don't think you got the point. Crockford is also part of the committee btw.

Comment: This is the logical reason for why strict mode defaults this to undefined. The other logical reason is efficiency, the other logical reason is that `this === window` is confusing and leaks global scope as a token into functions

Comment: @jAndy: Thanks for the answer. This makes sense. I also found a compact explanation of the changes to **this** on http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/javascript-strict-mode/: "Most notably, if the first argument to call or apply is null or undefined, the this value of the invoked function will not be converted to the global object."

Comment: @jAndy: it was a response to Rob W, sorry.

Comment: Oh my god.. I've been debugging my nodejs app for almost two hours, and couldn't find what went wrong. Found this question, read your answer, and at the **"forgot to use the `new` keyword"** part, I've experienced my own *facepalm of the month* moment.

Answer (score 16):

There is a mechanism called "boxing" which wraps or change the `this` object before entering the context of the called function.
In your case, the value of `this` should be `undefined` because you are not calling the function as a method of an object.
If non strict mode, in this case, this is replaced by the `window` object.
In `strict` mode it's always unchanged, that's why it's `undefined` here.

You can find more information at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode

Comment: @samuel so how can we assign a variable to window object in strict mode??

Answer (score 13):

According to [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551932/this-inside-an-anonymous-function), you can use `this` inside anonymous functions, simply by calling `.call(this)` at the end of it.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    this.foo = "bar";
}).call(this);
```

Comment: Note that `this` will be the `Window` object in this case, which may not be desired

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Strict mode does not allow default binding, so try this:

```
**yourFunctionName.bind(this)**
```

I hope now it's working fine.