# Unable to get property of undefined or null reference - Windows 8 JS/CSS app

Tags: javascript, windows-8

Below is a snippet of my code. The error I am getting is that when I perform a search and call the method `_searchData`, it successfully calls the method `_lookUpSuccess`, however then returns the following error:

**JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property '_displayResult' of undefined or null reference**

when it tries to call the `_displayResult` method.

Why this may be?

```
(function () {

    // make this an object property/method eventually
    var displayResult = function (queryResult) {
        for (var i = 0; i < holder.length; i++) {
            //document.querySelector(".item-content .title").textContent = "FilmApp";
            document.querySelector(holder[i]).textContent = queryResult[i];
       }};

    // Creates a new page control with members
    ui.Pages.define(searchPageURI, {
       //...
        _searchData: function (queryText) {
            searchBase          = 'http://www.example.com/web-service2.php?termID=';
            searchFormat        = 'JSON';
            searchFormatPiece   = '&format=' + searchFormat;

            if (!window.Data) {  
                var searchUrl = searchBase + queryText + searchFormatPiece;
                WinJS.xhr({ url: searchUrl }).done(this._lookUpSuccess, this._lookUpFail, this._lookUpProgress);
            }else{
                document.querySelector(".titlearea .pagetitle").textContent = "There has been a computer malfunction - sort it the **** out!";
            }
        },

        _lookUpSuccess: function xhrSucceed(Result) {
            var response = JSON.parse(Result.responseText);
                if (response.response[0].Message === "Found") {
                    for (var x in response.response[1].term) {
                        content.push(response.response[1].term[x]);
                    };
                    this._displayResult(content);
                    //displayResult(content);
                    return content;
                } else {
                    content.push("Not Found", "Not Found");
                    return content;
                }
         },

        _lookUpFail: function xhrFail(Result) { document.querySelector(".titlearea .pagetitle").textContent = "Got Error"; },
        _lookUpProgress: function xhrProgress(Result) { document.querySelector(".titlearea .pagetitle").textContent = "No Result 2"; },

        _displayResult: function (queryResult) {
            var holder;
            holder = [DefDiv, DescDiv];

            for (var i = 0; i < holder.length; i++) {
                //document.querySelector(".item-content .title").textContent = "FilmApp";
                document.querySelector(holder[i]).textContent = queryResult[i];
            };
        },

    });

    // End of UI.page.define    

    // #2 This method is run on application load
    WinJS.Application.addEventListener("activated", function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === appModel.Activation.ActivationKind.search) {
            args.setPromise(ui.processAll().then(function () {
                if (!nav.location) {
                    nav.history.current = { location: Application.navigator.home, initialState: {} };
                }
            return nav.navigate(searchPageURI, { queryText: args.detail.queryText });
            }));
        }
    });

    // #3 
    appModel.Search.SearchPane.getForCurrentView().onquerysubmitted = function (args) { nav.navigate(searchPageURI, args); };

})();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this line of code:

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: searchUrl }).done(this._lookUpSuccess, this._lookUpFail, this._lookUpProgress);
```

You are passing `_lookupSuccess` as the done handler function, but when it is called, the value of `this` is no longer what you want it to be because that will be set by the internals of whatever calls the done handler.  Passing `this._lookUpSuccess` as the function just passes the function.  It doesn't pass the value of `this`.  So, when `this._lookUpSuccess` is called with the wrong `this`, any references to `this` inside of it will not find the expected properties on it (thus the error you see).

You can fix it like this which saves the `this` value in a local variable and then use it when calling `_lookUpSuccess()`:

```
var self = this;
WinJS.xhr({ url: searchUrl }).done(function(result) {self._lookUpSuccess(result)}, this._lookUpFail, this._lookUpProgress);
```

This is a very common work-around for reattaching the proper `this` value in callbacks.

Comment: Thanks very much, this has worked, however it has introduced a new problem in the `lookUpSuccess` method. Now I get ` Unable to get property 'responseText' of undefined or null reference` as if making that amendment has stopped any values being passed to `_lookUpSuccess`

Comment: @James - yes, you have to pass along the result value.  I've modified my answer to show how you do that.  Note: you have have the exact same issue with `_lookUpFail` and `_lookUpProgress` if they need the `this` ptr.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks very much for this help. A very useful bit of troubleshooting to know!

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved a problem I had been stuck on for the past hour. :D

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
this._displayResult(content);
```

There, `this` is apparently `undefined` or `null`

Comment: I thought this originally but then saw the following link which suggested it should be `undefined` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822561/why-is-this-in-an-anonymous-function-undefined-when-using-strict