# What is the scope of a variable defined within a function expression in strict mode?

Tags: javascript, scope, function-expression

As I understand, when a variable is defined it gets attached to the 'closest' local scope via `this`.

If no scope is set locally, the closest scope becomes `window`.

In **strict mode**, however, the local scope is set to undefined instead of `window`, [as part of the ECMAscript 5 spec designed to limit misuse of the global scope.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822561/why-is-this-in-an-anonymous-function-undefined-when-using-strict)

---

Using an [immediately invoked function expression pattern](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and strict mode for creating a jQuery plugin

```
;( function( $, window ){
   "use strict";
   var myScope = this;
   var myVar = 1;

   var myFunction = function(){
     console.log( myScope, myVar );
   } 

   $.myFunc = myFunction;

})( jQuery, window );
```

the local scope (context) isn't created (via a function call) and thus set to undefined.

If the local scope is undefined and `window.myVar` is undefined, what is the scope of the variable `myVar` and how do you access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this context variable` has not anything to do with *Scope*, in terms of how ECMAscript implements *Lexical scoping* underneath.

`this` will always reference the *object of invocation*, which can change during run-time, whereas the *scope* / *context* cannot get changed. You got two function invocations there, each of those has its own *Execution Context* and its own *Activation Object* respectively *Lexical Environment Record*, which are used by the implementation to store any *local* data like *formal paramteres, variables and function declarations*.

---

What you are actually trying to achieve here, is to create a *hash* / *namespace object* which serves as container to hold data. Therefore, you shouldn't assign `this`, but just create your own *Object*.

```
var myScope = { };  // respectively Object.create( null );
```

In *strict mode*, the implementation will just set `this` to `undefined` for any function which got invocated *as is*. That means, the value of `this` is decided of **how** a function gets called. In your case, its a self-executing function and hence, its `this` will always be `undefined` in *strict mode* and `window` (*global*) in *non strict mode*.

Comment: I'm asking what is the object context of myVar. I guess since they simply decided to not set it to window, the answer is precisely, undefined. I thought that assigning a value to a variable implied there was some context that I should have access to, and if it's not `this` or `window`, then it should be something.

Comment: @qodeninja: exactly. It still depends on how a function gets called, but in your case, the `this` value will always contain `undefined` in strict mode.

Comment: @qodeninja: your same code without 'use strict' will also not assign the variable to window, but the underlying context doesn't change between the two situations. In other words, without strict, you still wouldn't be able to do `window.myVar` or `myScope.myVar`

Comment: @JimDeville: of course he would ! Without *strict mode*, `this` would just be a reference to `window` (if I got you right). He won't be able to access the variable `myVar` from "outside", but he would of course be able to access anything he wrote into the global object via that reference.

Comment: @jAndy: but since it is module scoped, and `myVar` is declared with `var`, it won't get exposed on `this`. IOW, you still cannot do `myScope.myVar` or `window.myVar`

Comment: @JimDeville: oh... no I got it. Yes you're right with that of course. What I meant was, in *non strict mode*, he could do like `myVar.foo = 42;` and would be able to access `window.foo` from anywhere else, since both reference the *global object*.

Comment: ah, yes (assuming you meant `myScope`, not `myvar` in that comment), on that, we agree.

Answer (score 1):

`myVar` is scoped to the containing closure. When I run your code, and then run $.myFunc(), the output is `undefined 1`, since `myVar` is still present in that closure. There is, however, no way to access `myVar` from outside of the closure. That is the same mechanism used to implement private variables in JS.

What @jAndy is saying is also true, `this` is unrelated to scope, and in this case the `this` of the anonymous function is `undefined`