# Function to Array Prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, ecmascript-6

I did a sort function that passing an array as a parameter return a new array with the index positions sorted by the name of the item.

*P.E: if the input is `["dog", "cat", "tiger"]` the expected output will be `[1, 0, 2]`*

### Without Prototype method

```
let sortIndexes = (a) => {
    var aClone = a.slice(0);
    return a.sort().map(x => aClone.indexOf(x));
}

let animals = ["dog", "cat", "tiger"];
var result = sortIndexes(animals); 
console.log(result) // [1, 0, 2]
```

Well, **this code works**, but I think is better do the same adding an **Array Prototype** method. And I try it...

### With Prototype

```
Array.prototype.sortIndexes = () => {
    var aClone = this.slice(0); //Console Error in this line
    return this.sort().map(x => aClone.indexOf(x));
}

let animals = ["dog", "cat", "tiger"];
var result = animals.sortIndexes();
```

I expected the same result that without using prototype, but this error console occurs:

`Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`

### How can do this using Array Prototype?

*Thanks!*

Comment: Please read [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the beauty of [`Arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this),

```
Array.prototype.sortIndexes = function(){
    var aClone = this.slice(0); //Console Error in this line
    return this.sort().map(x => aClone.indexOf(x));
}

let animals = ["dog", "cat", "tiger"];
var result = animals.sortIndexes(); 

console.log(result); // [1, 0, 2]
```

Arrow function will bind the `lexical scope` into it automatically. Here in your case the lexical scope is `window`. So `window.slice` is undefined. Hence it is throwing error.

And the main rule is that you cannot [force the scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Invoked_through_call_or_apply) of an arrow function with another one by using bind/call/etc.. So we have to be very careful while deciding when to use arrow functions.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined` means that the context `this` is `undefined` (but not `window` as you mention). Probably `strict mode` is enabled.

Comment: And it's not the problem in `lexical scope`. It's the `context` of the function invocation: `this`.

Comment: Scope and `this` are different things.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin Arrow function decides the `this` based on which scope it is getting executed.

Comment: Arrow functions don't decide anything. They simply resolve `this` lexically. This also means that the scope is determined when / where the function is *defined*, **not** where/when it is *executed*.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for correcting the words usage of mine. (Non native english speaker here) I was trying to tell about execution of this `var x = () => { "something"; }` code, not `x()`.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Probably a formulation like this is easier to follow: "Arrow functions keep the context `this` of the function from the lexical scope where it was defined. That's why you lost the array instance, because `this` is `undefined` in `.sortIndexes()`'s outer scope (`strict mode` is enabled)".

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin That's fine. But I am still wondering on which case, the `this` of an arrow function would becomes undefined. https://jsfiddle.net/2vvf9x98/1/ I tested it here with strict mode. Still cannot repro what OP said. May be OP mentioned the error message in wrong manner?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Your fiddle still has `window` as this. Just wrap it into an IIFE with strict mode enabled: https://jsfiddle.net/kmnpt9em/

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin Your explanations and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9822631/1209018 has cleared my doubts. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions don't bind `this` to the element being iterated, instead `this` simply remains bound to the enclosing scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Nit: The don't *bind* `this` at all, they simply resolve `this` lexically, like any other variable.

Comment: @FelixKling `this` isn't a variable - it is a keyword that is bound to an object reference and that binding cannot be changed (unless a containing function is called with `call`, `apply`, `bind`, `forEach`, `map`, etc.). Arrow functions use the `lexical binding` of this. The binding process for `this` takes place when a function's Activation Object is created.

Comment: Sure. All I am saying is that arrow functions are not *binding* `this` in the sense how `.bind` binds `this`. *"The binding process for this takes place when a function's Activation Object is created."* Activation objects don't exist anymore in ES6. `this` is not bound in arrow functions: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function-environment-records: *"A function Environment Record is a declarative Environment Record that is used to represent the top-level scope of a function and, if the function is not an ArrowFunction, provides a `this` binding. "*

Comment: @FelixKling True, but then again, I didn't say they did bind as in `.bind()`, but they do actually bind.

Comment: Well, I hope my quote from the spec convinces you otherwise. I agree that `this` is not resolved *exactly* like other variables, but it is not bound. The relevant part of the spec is http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-resolvethisbinding and http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getthisenvironment .

Comment: I'll have to read up on the Activation Object deprecation, but from what I see, my statement still holds, `this` is a keyword and it does get bound (except in specific instances that the language specifies that it should not be bound). Arrow functions don't cause `this` to be bound, that's true, but `this` is still bound, it's just bound to the lexical scope.

Comment: In case there was a misunderstanding here, I'm only talking about arrow functions. Of course the environment of regular functions has a `this` binding.

Comment: Yes, I think we are having a circular discussion. You initially said that `this` resolves like any other variable and my main point here is that `this` isn't a variable and doesn't resolve like one. You can't, for example, set a value into this directly. It is a special keyword and it does get bound (except when the language says it shouldn't), rather than assigned.