# React (component) onClick method with parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem of putting the parameter into the function. I've tried several solutions I've found here on Stack Overflow, but without success.

Here is my code:

```
function mapStateToProps(store) { return { un: store.measurement.unsaved, pat: store.patient.patients }; }

class MeasUnsaved extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.showBtn = this.showBtn.bind(this);
        this.findPat = this.findPat.bind(this); this.createObj = this.createObj.bind(this);}
    findPat(id){
        let ps = this.props.pat.filter( p => (p.id === id) );
        return ps[0];
    }
    createObj(){
        let meas = [], i=0;
        this.props.un.forEach( u => {
            let pat = this.findPat(u.patId);
            let k = { date: u.date, fnote: u.fnote, patId: u.patId, name: pat.lastName+' '+pat.name, pos: i };
            i++;
            meas.push(k);
        });
        return meas;
    }
    showBtn(val){
        console.log(val);
    }
    render(){
        const unsaved = this.createObj();
        return (
            <Well>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Unsaved Measurement</legend>
                    <p>Unsaved Meas. will be lost after logout.</p>
                    {this.props.un.length === 0 && <p> You have 0 unsaved measurement </p>}
                    {this.props.un.length > 0 &&
                    <Table responsive>
                        <thead>
                            <tr><th>Date</th><th>Note</th><th>Patient</th><th>Actions</th></tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {
                            unsaved.map(function(u){
                                return (
                                    <tr key={u.date+u.patId.toString()}>
                                        <td>{u.date}</td>
                                        <td>{u.fnote}</td>
                                        <td>{u.name}</td>
                                        <td><Button bsSize="small" onClick={this.showBtn(u.pos)}>Show</Button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                );
                            })
                        }
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                    }
                </fieldset>
            </Well>
        );
    }
} export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MeasUnsaved) ;
```

Here is the error:

> ERROR: Uncaught Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showBtn' of undefined at onClick

Comment: You didn't even post any onClick.

Comment: Are you sure that's the error you get? `show tn` not `showBtn`? Also, what line?

Comment: on the showBtn call you just need to put this or the e. in the function is where you can access the properties of the event

Comment: Doesn't make sense anyway since there's no `e` defined, so you'll need to fix that as well.

Comment: The reason your solution works is because the "arrow function" has a bound lexical scope("this" is never changing and pre-set).

Comment: FYI, there is a remark from someone under your (reposted) answer below that identifies a problem with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems ;

1. you're using "this" inside "map" - see ["this" is undefined inside map function Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148827/this-is-undefined-inside-map-function-reactjs)
2. you're executing this.showBtn on each row, what you'll want is to pass a function as an argument - this should be enough :

   onClick={() => this.showBtn(u.pos)}

Comment: you'll need to sort both of these issues for your code to work as far as I can see(without running your code myself)

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, you are getting the error...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showBtn' of undefined

... at the line whre you are accessing `this.showBtn`. On that line, [`this` is undefined because it's inside an anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822561/why-is-this-in-an-anonymous-function-undefined-when-using-strict).

If you bind that function to `this` it will no longer be undefined:

```
unsaved.map(function (u) {
    return (
        <tr key={u.date+u.patId.toString()}>
            <td>{u.date}</td>
            <td>{u.fnote}</td>
            <td>{u.name}</td>
            <td><Button bsSize="small" onClick={this.showBtn(u.pos)}>Show</Button></td>
        </tr>
    );
}.bind(this))
```

Alternatively, you can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
unsaved.map((u) =>
    <tr key={u.date+u.patId.toString()}>
        <td>{u.date}</td>
        <td>{u.fnote}</td>
        <td>{u.name}</td>
        <td><Button bsSize="small" onClick={this.showBtn(u.pos)}>Show</Button></td>
    </tr>
})
```

**Secondly**, to make your code work, you need to pass a function in `onClick{}`, but you are doing `onClick={this.showBtn(e.pos)}`. What this does it immediately call `this.showBtn(e.pos)` and pass the return value (which is undefined) to `onClick={}`.

Instead, do this ...

```
onClick={this.showBtn.bind(this, u.pos)}
```

... or this (using arrow function) ...

```
onClick={() => this.showBtn(u.pos)}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Solved by:

```
unsaved.map((u)=>{
                                return (
                                    <tr key={u.date+u.patId.toString()}>
                                        <td>{u.date}</td>
                                        <td>{u.fnote}</td>
                                        <td>{u.name}</td>
                                        <td><Button bsSize="small" onClick={(event) => this.showBtn(u.pos)}>Show</Button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                );
                            })
```

Comment: not a good option because render will create a new function each time.