# Javascript is throwing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined" when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning how to make a Javascript plugin to make a modal window appear. [I'm trying to learn using this codepen](https://codepen.io/kenwheeler/pen/LvGjK/). When I try to test it somewhere else, I get the following error when the page loads:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'raModal' of undefined
>
> ```
> at raDialog.js:5
> at raDialog.js:158
> ```

Looking at line 5, I can see that the error is referring to the start of the function that will construct the modal I want to display, ***but I don't quite understand why it's throwing an error on that line.***

```
"use strict";
(function() {
     // Make the constructor
       this.raModal = function(){ //Line 5, error occurs here.

          // Create global element references
          this.closeButton = null;
          this.modal = null;
          this.overlay = null;

          // Define option defaults
          var defaults = {
             autoOpen: false,
             className: "",
             closeButton: true,
             content: "",
             maxWidth: 500,
             minWidth: 280,
             minHeight: 150,
             maxHeight: 700,
             overlay: true,
             onOK: "",
             onClose: ""
          };

          // Create options by extending defaults with the passed in arugments
          if (arguments[0] && typeof arguments[0] === "object") {
              this.options = extendDefaults(defaults, arguments[0]);
          }
          if(this.options.autoOpen === true){
            this.open();
          }

       };

     //More code...

  }()); //Line 158 also produces an error, might be related to Line 5's error.
```

I'm able to reproduce the error in a JSFiddle.
[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Miega/j95ny2bq/)

Any explanations why this error is occurring is appreciated.

Comment: In a strict environment `this` inside a function will be `undefined`. For the global object in a browser, use `window`. -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `strict` environment `this` inside a `function` will be `undefined`.

For the global object in a browser, use `window`.

```js
'use strict';

(function () {
  console.log(this);

  window.foo = 'bar';
  console.log(window.foo);
}());
```

Or you can use the `new` keyword:

```js
'use strict';

(new function () {
  this.foo = 'bar';
  console.log(this.foo);
}());
```

See [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it) for more information.

Comment: I'm new to using `use strict` so I didn't know that was the issue! Thanks a bunch for the information.The code is working now.

Comment: `use strict` makes debugging a bit easier (among other things) by preventing certain actions from being taken, and throwing more exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is `undefined` within an anonymous function in strict mode. See the `console.log(this);` that I added to the first line of your code - then try running it without `"use strict"` and notice how it works as you had expected.

```js
"use strict";

(function() {
       console.log(this);
       this.raModal = function(){ //Line 5, error occurs here.

          // Create global element references
          this.closeButton = null;
          this.modal = null;
          this.overlay = null;

          // Define option defaults
          var defaults = {
             autoOpen: false,
             className: "",
             closeButton: true,
             content: "",
             maxWidth: 500,
             minWidth: 280,
             minHeight: 150,
             maxHeight: 700,
             overlay: true,
             onOK: "",
             onClose: ""
          };

          // Create options by extending defaults with the passed in arugments
          if (arguments[0] && typeof arguments[0] === "object") {
              this.options = extendDefaults(defaults, arguments[0]);
          }
          if(this.options.autoOpen === true){
            this.open();
          }

       };

     //More code...

  }()); //Line 158 also produces an error, might be related to Line 5's error.
```

[Check out this other SO question that addresses this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822561/why-is-this-in-an-anonymous-function-undefined-when-using-strict)