# Reactjs app - Not able to fetch data with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am new to React, and in my very simple app, I am just trying to read and display a json data (of Companies and jobs they have posted). Using React 16.3.0 and react-dom 16.3.2 and axios 0.18.0

My code is below and the final output should show the data I am trying to fetch in each row in a nice format.

But its not rendering at all and getting error - I must be doing some very stupid mistake here.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
    at isURLSameOrigin (isURLSameOrigin.js:57)
    at dispatchXhrRequest (xhr.js:109)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xhrAdapter (xhr.js:12)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:59)
```

Here's my code and here's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rohanpaul/2w9f8c97/)

```
<!-- DOCTYPE HTML -->
<html>
<head>
<title>Your First React Project</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.component {    

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { jobs: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount () {
    // var th = this;

    this.serverRequest =
      axios.get(this.props.source)

        .then(function(result) {
          this.setState({
            jobs: result.data.jobs
          });
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
        this.serverRequest.abort();
    }


    render () {
        return (
            <div>
              <h1>Jobs!</h1>

              {/* Don't have an ID to use for the key, URL work ok? */}

              {this.state.jobs.map(function(job) {
                return (
                  <div key={job.url} className="job">
                    <a href={job.url}>
                      {job.company_name}
                      is looking for a
                      {job.term}
                      {job.title}
                    </a>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
      </div>

        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App source="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rohan-paul/b74bf6ef1adfdb92e0af5783e6c93a71/raw/bdffbbcb50128c03dd9edc90dbeb85e88c70ebc4/jobs.json"/>, document.getElementById('#root'));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's fixed jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n85v504b/2/

The problem is you're making cross origin request which is not allowed by default. I've changed the axios call to:

```
axios.request({
        method: "get",
        url: this.props.source,
        crossDomain: true
      })
```

Also changed the promise fullfillment since this was undefined (reason explained here [Why is "this" in an anonymous function undefined when using strict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822561/why-is-this-in-an-anonymous-function-undefined-when-using-strict))

```
then((result) => this.setState({jobs: result.data.jobs}))
```

Comment: Thanks  a ton mate !!