# how to get the reference("this") of current object in 'use strict mode' in java script

Tags: javascript

According to my knowledge and experience we can not access "this" in strict mode in JavaScript then how we get the reference of current object? can anyone explain it, thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822561/why-is-this-in-an-anonymous-function-undefined-when-using-strict

Comment: i think this question is related to anonymous function as you mentioned the link.